# Nautilus alternative for debian

Tags: debian, nautilus

I am having a hard time installing Marlin on Debian. PPA command doesn't seem to be working in Debian. Is there any other way I can get rid of Nautilus and install another alternative? Or better yet get Nautilus to not eat up CPU like cereals for breakfast.

Comment: Not that your question is misplaced, but this has high potential for some serious discussion bordering a flame war... ;)

Comment: I haven't been able to test them out yet. Will make a decision when I've tested them. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Nemo is a nice alternative - it this file manager for Cinnamon, and is based on Nautilus - [see here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-nemo-and-set-it-as-the-default-file-manager/).

The problem is, in the latest versions, the cinnamon screensaver installed with it means that the screen is locked twice...

So eventually I gave up on Nemo, and just set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in keyboard shortcuts to run the command `killall nautilus`

You can also run `tracker-control -k` which will stop the tracker thing, sometimes causes Nautilus to crash (in the Gnome desktop atleast). (I set this as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in keyboard shortcuts).

Also, in when starting Gnome, Nautilus is started in the background, and can often shoot to 100%CPU - you can stop this by running `gnome-session-properties` and un-ticking it.

To remove nautilus on Debian, running `sudo apt-get remove nautilus` should work. BEWARE, it will may try and remove other things you want, e.g. Gnome Tweak Tool, some Media players, etc.

You could run `sudo apt-get remove nautilus`, and then run `sudo apt-get install nautilus`, as it is not always nautilus that cause the trouble. but some of the installed extensions *(integrated terminal for instance)*. Running both of these commands would remove the extensions as dependencies, and then re-install nauilus **on its own**, so it may not cause so much trouble.

---

For installing marlin, it is not in the usual repositories, so this may help:

http://blog.desdelinux.net/instala-marlin-en-debian-testing/

Comment: Hi wilf thank you for your answer. The problem with killall nautilus is that it always respawns ... I tried gnome-sesion-properties and I get this "No protocol specified

** (gnome-session-properties:13808): WARNING **: Unable to start: Cannot open display: "

Comment: killall -w nautilus is another alternative as well. The reason I assigned it as keyboard shortcut was because -the flipping thing kept re spawning. Then instead of opening a terminal etc, I just had to press the keyboard shortcut. Also, I have just added another option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Thunar, it's really lightweight and should provide a nice experience while browsing.

[image: Thunar Picture]
It is also possible to enable buttons, and is usable from an under-clocked Raspberry Pi to a super-computer - wilf

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L. Could you expand this a bit and explain why? Though your answer may be correct it would be more useful if it included some actual details as to why. Screenshots, etc. might make this A more valuable to future visitors as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great alternative for nautilus -- SpaceFM. Check out the screen below:

[image: spacefm]

> SpaceFM is a multi-panel tabbed file and desktop manager for Linux
> with built-in VFS, udev- or HAL-based device manager, customizable
> menu system, and bash integration. SpaceFM is popular among novice and
> power users alike for its stability, speed, convenience and
> flexibility.
>
> Depends
>
> - GTK+ v2 or v3 (2.18 thru 3.x supported)
> - udev or HAL
> - desktop-file-utils
> - shared-mime-info
>
> Optional:
>
> - udevil or udisks or pmount
> - startup-notification
> - custom terminal emulators
> - multiple su front-ends
> - plugins
>
> http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/

See also the manual: http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/spacefm-manual-en.html

SpaceFM is a pretty powerful tool. You can install it with aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a look on this nice [Comparison of File Managers (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers) about what's available. Next thing I suggest looking up which File Browsers [Lightweighted GNU/Linux Distributons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution) use. Another great resource to look up the latter is [Distro Watch](http://distrowatch.org/), where I would look what lightweighted Distros use and give a look at their file managers.

As always, finding a well-balanced blend of hardware resources (what is possible) and functionality with an understandable dash of desire for convenience. Personally, I am highly satisfied with Thunar, as - for me (!!!) - it provides exactly what I want and need on a G. At the same time I know a lot of people what are not happy with it.

Also a personal note: Not that your question is misplaced, but this has high potential for some serious discussion bordering a flame war... ;)

Answer (score -1):

Pcmanfm looks like Nautilus, so you may find it to be a great alternative.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use dolphin, and recommend it if you want a more featureful FM. Of course, your mileage may vary.